# jQueryUI modal confirms deletion of ajax-loaded row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a PHP script (ajax.php) which loads content from a MySQL db. That script refreshes new content every N seconds via AJAX. The AJAX content has three links of which one is to archive the row in MySQL. When a user clicks the archive button, I want a jQueryUI dialog to open confirming deletion. Pressing cancel will abort, while OK will trigger an AJAX submission to delete the row from MySQL. [Deleting row from table with modal form confirmation (jQuery UI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230523/deleting-row-from-table-with-modal-form-confirmation-jquery-ui) is an example of the dialog half of what I want to do. I need this to work along with the ajax/refresh.

Because of the link itself being loaded by AJAX, I cannot run the dialog (or the delete script). How do I load the dialog script and perform the AJAX delete submission? I'm trying to use the GlobalEval but I do not understand the documentation. The examples I've found seem to be for setting variables only. The following script is what I'm trying to build it from:

```
var id = $('.refreshN').data('id');
var table = $('.refreshN').data('table');
var rtime = $('.refreshN').data('time');
$('.refreshN').load('ajax.php?id='+id+'&table='+table).fadeIn("slow");

var autoLoad = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $('.refreshN').load('ajax.php?id='+id+'&table='+table).fadeIn(5000);
    var script = $(function (){
        $('.modalLink').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
    eval(script);
}, rtime); // refresh page every N seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable `script` with an normal javascript function and add `()` to execute it.
Try this instead of your current js:

```
var id = $('.refreshN').data('id');
var table = $('.refreshN').data('table');
var rtime = $('.refreshN').data('time');
$('.refreshN').load('ajax.php?id='+id+'&table='+table).fadeIn("slow");

var autoLoad = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $('.refreshN').load('ajax.php?id='+id+'&table='+table).fadeIn(5000);
}, rtime); // refresh page every N seconds

$(document).on('click','.modalLink',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this but still no luck. Refreshing works fine, but the archive link still follows like a standard HTML link with no dialog. I'm assuming based off of what I've read elsewhere, I need to call the dialog script on the link after it's loaded, but I'm not quite tracking on how to do so.

Comment: Aah ok, now i understand your problem. That's because the event listener isn't listening anymore after the AJAX refresh. The AJAX request will take time and the bind event will be done before the AJAX request is ready. So that means your `click` bind will try binding before the HTML is even ready. Use `document.on` to archieve binding dynamic content. I updated my answer. Try it, i think this will solve your problem.